# printf flag '%u' on a 1byte variable treats it as 4bytes all ones

Tags: c

-1 in a 1byte variable is 1111 1111
now when I try to printf it as if It was an unsigned integer
I expect it to be 255
but some how It's treating it as if It was 4bytes all containing ones saying "0xff ff ff ff"
which is 2 to the 32 minus 1 .
why is that?
and why it assumes the remaining 3 bytes as all ones?

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main ( ) {
    char g = -1; 
    printf ( "g is %u \n" , g );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char` and `unsigned` have different signedness, so I believe it essentially first converts to `(int)-1` and then `unsigned`.

Comment: Try `%hhu` instead of `%u`.

Comment: nice but can you please explain what does %h flag means? and why do we use two of those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `%u` specifier with `printf` you are telling it to expect an `int`, which on your system is apparently 32-bits. So, `-1` as a *32-bit int* on your system is represented by `0xffffffff`.

It then prints this as an unsigned int, giving you the result you're seeing.

As mentioned in the comments, replace the `%u` specifier with `%hhu` to avoid the promotion of your 8-bit signed value into a 32-bit signed value.

For a list of C printf specifiers, see [this page](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) on cplusplus.com.

The `%h` specifier indicates a `short int` which is 16-bits. The `%hh` specifier indicates a *short* `short int` or just `char` which is a single byte.

Comment: nice but can you please explain what does %h flag means? and why do we use two of those?

Comment: Please do not use “integer” to mean `int`. An [integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer) is a whole number or the negative of a whole number. The word “integer” does not mean C’s `int` type. Further, for a `%u` conversion, an `unsigned int` should be provided, not an `int`. Additionally, passing −1 for `%hhu` is technically wrong; an `unsigned char` value should be passed, and −1 is not an `unsigned char` value. And there is no such thing as a “*short* `short int`”.

Comment: I have edited to take into account your suggestion re: "integer." However, the unsigned to signed issue is something the OP was specifically addressing. I specifically formatted "short short int" as I did to indicate what you're saying. I felt using the word "short" twice helped to demonstrate the reason for two 'h' characters in the specifier.

Answer (score 0):

For starters in your program the type `char` behaves as the type `signed char`.

In this call

```
printf ( "b is %u \n" , g );
```

the expression `g` of the type `char` is promoted to the type `int` due to the integer promotions preserving the sign bit.  The value -1 in an object of the type int for 2s complement system is represented like `0xff ff ff ff` provided that `sizeof( int )` is equal to 4..

It will more correctly to write

```
printf ( "b is %u \n" , ( unsigned int )g );
```

To get the expected result you need to write

```
printf ( "b is %u \n" , ( unsigned char )g );
```